# JerseyJUint test - how to load OSGI-INF/blueprint/config.xml file programmatically in java

Tags: java, rest, osgi, karaf

I am writing Junit for restful webservices. I want load my config file which is located at **/src/test/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/config.xml**,  so before executing any of my test cases, all the beans defined in config.xml file should get initialize. Could you pls tell me how can programmatically I retrieve all the beans without using spring.
Please help, I am new to OSGI and Karaf.

Answer (score 0):

I hardly think that you will find an effective way to unite tests on code that uses OSGi related technology. There are, however, several ways to write tests with JUnit annotations and run them on an OSGi container. To use these tools, you have to collect all of the dependencies that your bundle needs. You can call it as a half integration test and half unit test.

These tools are:

- [Pax exam](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/spaces/PAXEXAM4/overview): It will start an OSGi container for each of your test method (as much as I remember, I used it several years ago)
- [BndTools](http://bndtools.org/): If you develop your modules with BndTools, you can also write tests that can run during an ant, maven or gradle build
- [eosgi-maven-plugin](http://www.everit.org/eosgi-maven-plugin/): With the integration-test goal it installs all the dependencies of the project onto an OSGi container. You must register an instance of your test class as an OSGi service with specific service properties. Your test class must contain JUnit4 annotations. There is also an [eclipse plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/everit-osgi-eclipse-plugin) which makes it possible for you to start the test container and see the fresh test results in Eclipse after they are executed. For this choice, there is [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNH6JVmAcIQ&t=6s) to help gettin started